# how to have UITextField push to a new ViewController when a string in an NSArray is used?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsarray

I have created a `UITextField` called `textField`, an `NSArray` of strings called `keywordsArray`, and a submit button.

What I want to have happen is that if the user's text input to the `UITextField` contains one of the strings in the `keywordsArray` it would push to one view controller, if not it would push to another.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
self.keywordsArray=@[@"funny, @"tall", @"handsome"];
[submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showresponse:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(BOOL)showresponse:(UIButton *)sender{
    YesViewController *yesViewController=[[YesViewController alloc]init];
    NoViewController *noViewController=[[NoViewController alloc]init];

    if ([self.textField.text isEqualToString:self.keywordArray]) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:yesViewController animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:noViewController animated:YES];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

but then it says

> "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'"

How do i make it so that if someone were to input "he is tall" it would push to `YesViewController` because "tall" is a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if ([self.textField.text isEqualToString:self.keywordArray])
```

is where your error is. Basically, it doesn't make any sense to compare a string to an array.

Instead of what you're doing you should be checking if the `text` from the text field contains any of the words from the array. That means iterating over the array and checking each item.

That might looks something like:

```
for (NSString *word in self.keywordArray) {
    if ([self.textField.text rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:yesViewController animated:YES];
        return YES;
    }
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:noViewController animated:YES];
return YES;
```

Comment: p.s. you probably want to look at using `rangeOfString:options:` if you do this so you can specify case insensitive range detection.

Comment: it crashed when i implemented this. I simply swapped this for where my if statement was am i doing it wrong or do i have to add anything else besides this?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I agree with Wain's part of code

```
for (NSString *word in self.keywordArray) {
    if ([self.textField.text rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound) {
 ...
```

But pushing view controller in BOOL function is very wrong.
I would write your method like this:

```
// In your example, you missed to close quotes for word funny
self.keywordsArray=@[@"funny", @"tall", @"handsome"];
[submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showresponse:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)showresponse:(UIButton *)sender{
    // Initialize view controller which you'll need, not both.
    if ([self containsKeyword:self.textField.text]) {
        YesViewController *yesViewController=[[YesViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:yesViewController animated:YES];
    } else {
        NoViewController *noViewController=[[NoViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:noViewController animated:YES];
    }
}

// Now this method can be reusable for any other field or controler                     
- (BOOL)containsKeyword:(NSString*)text {
    for (NSString *word in self.keywordArray) {
        if ([text rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: it does not identify the method containsKeyword:

Answer (score 0):

```
self.keywordsArray=@[@"funny, @"tall", @"handsome"];
[submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showresponse:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(BOOL)showresponse:(UIButton *)sender
{

    for (NSString *word in self.keywordArray) 
    {
      if ([self.textField.text rangeOfString:word options].location != NSNotFound) 
      {
         YesViewController *yesViewController=[[YesViewController alloc]init];

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:yesViewController animated:YES];
         return YES;
       }
    }

  NoViewController *noViewController=[[NoViewController alloc]init];
  self.navigationController pushViewController:noViewController animated:YES];
 }
```